# Using Pandas in python while converting date to datetime datatype from obj , I am not getting my dates properly converted. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, python-datetime

[image: Date before conversion]

[image: Date after conversion]

Please have look at both these images, especially Dates from Sno 32. The month column and day column are not properly converted . How can I make this correct? I have already referred to questions regarding timeseries but haven't found any answer to this kind of issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem pandas by default parse months first if possible.

---

You can specify the format as `DD/MM/YY`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
```

Or try using `dayfirst=True` parameter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or if create DataFrame from file use `parse_dates` and `dayfirst=True` parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
```